# Can we use AWS IAM Role to upload a file through rest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I don't want to keep access key and secret keys in my code, using an IAM role can i upload a file to my s3 bucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is running on an EC2 instance then yes you can.. in fact Amazon advises that you do not use access keys in your code and you use instance roles instead.

What you will need to do is:

1) Write up an IAM Policy with the permissions you'd like the instance to have.

2) Create an IAM Role and attach the Policy you've created to the Role. The "Trust Relationship" of the Role should be ec2.amazonaws.com. See [Modifying a role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_manage_modify.html) for details.

3) Launch a new EC2 Instance and set the Role as the Role you created in step 2.

Comment: Can i find any sample code which uses IAM role to download a file from S3 ?

Comment: If this is for a quick thing you can just add the policy "AmazonS3FullAccess" to the Role your instance will use. However, I strongly suggest you use the principle of least privilege.